# How to go from HTML to python, return to html, then alter a variable in a processing script?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, processing

My project:

I want to make a  simple webpage (only run on my local machine - not connected to internet) that, when you press a button on the client side, runs a python script that runs [dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu), and returns the title of the song. I then want to use the song title to alter a variable in a processing script, which will display different visualizations based on the song.

So far, I have a working python script (testPython.py) that will recognize a song a return a title as a string:

```
from dejavu import Dejavu
from dejavu.recognize import MicrophoneRecognizer
main():
    config = {
        "database": {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "user": "root",
            "passwd": "Password",
            "db": "dejavu",
        }
    }
    djv = Dejavu(config)
    song = djv.recognize(MicrophoneRecognizer, seconds=10)
    return song.get("song_name") #this is a string
```

I have html + AJAX script that can call a python function and alter an HTML element based on it, and a canvas element with the processing script

```
    $('button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: "testPython.py",
         success: function(response) {
             $("#test").css("color", "red");
         }
        });
    });

    .
    .
    .

    <canvas data-processing-sources="testProcessing.pde"></canvas>
```

And I have a processing script (the change in output based on a variable isn't implemented, but it shouldn't be complicated)

```
    void setup(){
    ...
    }

    void draw(){
    ...
    }
```

How do I put these all together, so the result from python/ dejavu affects the processing script's output?

(also I know this is messy; I'm new to pretty much everything here except python and html, and I overestimated the complexity of the project)

Comment: Which part of this isn't working?

Comment: Getting the return value from python and sending it to the processing script. When accessing the python code through AJAX I'm confused on how to use the return value to alter something in the processing code. You answer helps with the "using it in the processing code" part, but not the "getting a return value from AJAX" part

Comment: Then that's a separate question then. You need to split your problem up into smaller steps. One step is getting it from AJAX to JavaScript. Another is getting it from JavaScript to Processing. But I'm not sure what your question is- can't you just set a value or call a function from the AJAX callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the **Writing Documents that Combine Processing and JavaScript Code** section of [the Processing.js JavaScript Quick Start Guide](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#combineprocessingandjavascript).

That guide explains exactly how to mix Processing.js and JavaScript.

Specifically, you've got two options: either have your Processing.js code call JavaScript functions and variables, or have your JavaScript code call Processing functions.

In the end it's all being converted to JavaScript, so it's all the same thing.

Also, please get into the habit of breaking your problem down into smaller pieces. You said you've got the Python part working, so now isolate the rest of it in a simpler example that uses a hard-coded variable in JavaScript that you want to get in Processing. Try to put together a little example (preferably on JSFiddle or CodePen), and post a link to that (in a new question) if you get stuck. Good luck.